# PHP Mysql strange character convertion issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character, decoding

I'm trying to retrieve the header information of unknown websites entered by a user. The script i got works well. But on some links the Page title could have a character like this:

some-website: Let’s build from here

referring to this character: " ’ " but also for any other similar characters in this class. (If this character looks like a normal ' to you, then actually this is the dot with a curve type of this ' character )

This character when entered into the MySQL table becomes a pound sign with an elevated tm mark and breaks the calling script.

some-website: Let€™s build from here

A solution i know will work is to create a array and then push the text to the array and then json_encode the array, later when retrieving the data json_decode the array and create the $variable = array[0];

is there not a more standard / universal approach? Like a internal PHP encoding and decoding method for text strings before entering them into the database. The database for this project is < 5.3

Something like:
encodeURI(); or..

Comment: Hi, to your related post, It was very informative and I actually learnt quite a bit. Thank you. The encoding and conversions don't work for this and other characters like this one i specified. They change the character to something completely different which breaks the calling script. I need to change it before entering it into the DB and back again after calling it, before display

Comment: See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). The webpage you're retrieving has _some_ encoding. Depending on how you treat or parse it, it may or may not get converted to _some encoding_. You then insert it into the database over a connection which is set to expect _some encoding_. You then get it out via _some encoding_. You then output it to somewhere that expects _some encoding_. You need to ensure you specify the encodings at each of these steps correctly.

Comment: BTW, you can skip the array part in your JSON workaround, it doesn't make a difference whether you wrap the value in an array or not.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` so we can discuss whether the problem is during Inserting or during fetching.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Hi, yes about the JSON array part, it did not work as i thought.

Comment: I took a more close look at the data being parsed as you suggested and discovered that when the Variable reaches the PHP file, it has already changed all the special characters, like the one above. The issue was not with my database at all, but with the URL itself, i then added the encodeURIcomponent() in JavaScript to the URL parameter variable and used the rawurldecode() in PHP. This seems to handle all the odd characters like the one mentioned here. The calling script does not require extra conversions, and all is working now